# Upload a remote photo to an upload

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to upload a remote picture to Facebook using the Facebook PHP Library??

Instead of using

```
    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
    $args = array('message' => 'My Caption');
    $args['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);

    $data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
```

Instead of a **realpath($file)** I would like to use a remote path to an image for example:

```
http://myserver.com/image.jpg
```

I tried to replace the **realpath($file)** with a http link but I got the following error:

```
 Uncaught CurlException: 26: couldn't open file "http://mydomain.com/fb_images/EwrTsUqEuG.jpg"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to download the file to your server, then [file_put_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to store it in a temporary, local file for the upload FB transfer process, then [unlink()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) to delete the file afterwards.

```
<?php

# The URL for the Image to Transfer
$imageURL = 'http://server.com/the_image.jpg';
# Folder for Temporary Files
$tempFilename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tempFiles/';

# Unique Filename
$tempFilename .= uniqid().'_'.basename( $imageURL );

# Get the Image
if( $imgContent = @file_get_contents( $imageURL ) ){
  if( @file_put_contents( $tempFilename , $imgContent ) ){

    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
    $args = array('message' => 'My Caption');
    $args['image'] = '@' . realpath( $tempFilename );

    $data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);

    # Once done, delete the Temporary File
    unlink( $tempFilename );

  }else{
    # Failed to Save Image
  }
}else{
  # Failed to Get Image
}
```