# Facebook Image upload

Tags: php, facebook, image-uploading

I want to upload the image on the facebook but there is a problem. I am facing the following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26:
```

I found the exact problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116359/upload-a-remote-photo-to-an-upload)

The solution is give and he said to change the path as

```
# The URL for the Image to Transfer
$imageURL = 'http://server.com/the_image.jpg';
```

I did not understand what is meant by `http://server.com` either facebook.com or localhost??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$imageURL` means the url of the image you want to upload.

Example you want to upload an image which is hosted at some website. The the url to the image is the `$imageURL`.

It will be easier to explain if you posted some codes.

I think you should have posted your doubt in  the other question itself.

Comment: If te image is present on my computer then..?

Comment: Then directly assign it to $tempFilename variable. You can skip the file download part then.