# facebook api image is not uploading from url

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have the following code to upload image to my photos

```
  $args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');
          $args['image'] = '@' . realpath('http://sawalpk.com/storyboard_server/outputImage.png');

          $data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
          print_r($data);
```

If I put the image as `realpath('someImage.png')` It works. Remember the `someImage.png` is found the the same directory. While with the url of an external image it do not uploads and returns no data to debug. Any guru here to help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have to download the remote ([for e.x. via CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476212/save-image-from-url-with-curl-php/6476232#6476232) or file_get_contents()) file to the server and pass it via `realpath()` locally.

In fact, you send the request to Facebook Graph API, so you cannot include remote file.

Related problem: [Upload a remote photo to an upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116359/upload-a-remote-photo-to-an-upload)

I preffer CURL because of efficiency: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me:

```
$picUrl = 'http://sawalpk.com/storyboard_server/outputImage.png';
$photoId = $facebook->api("me/photos","POST",array('url'=>$picUrl,'message'=>"Photo caption"));
```

set 'url' parameter if you have image url instead of real path.

Comment: that worked for me too. removed the 'image' arg and replaced with 'url'